# Grails: is it possible to exclude a plugin dependency of another plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a grails 2.2.2 app, and have decided to use cache-ehcache plugin.

The problem is that this plugin depends on the cache plugin with version 1.0.0 and my application has the cache plugin version 1.0.1 (i think it is the default for grails 2.2.2). Therefore when i try to compile the app i always get the same message:

```
You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [cache-1.0.1]. Do you want to update to [cache-1.0.0]? [y,n]
```

I have to answer this question every time i compile the application. I tried to change the project plugin dependency to cache-1.0.1 in `.grails/2.2.2/my_project/plugins/cache-ehcache-1.0.0/dependencies.groovy` and `plugin.xml` files. It does not seem to work.

I know that it is possible to exclude jars from plugin dependencies but is it possible to exclude another plugin?

I tried changing the section of `BuildConfig.groovy` to:

```
plugins {
    ...  
    compile(':cache-ehcache:1.0.0') { excludes ":cache:1.0.0"}
}
```

but it still does not seem to work. I get the same question every time i compile the app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use as

```
plugins {
    ...  
    compile(':cache-ehcache:1.0.0') { excludes "cache"}
}
```

Comment: Also, you can use this syntax 
`compile ":events-push:1.0.M7", { excludes "resources" }`