# Deploying Grails WAR file from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 gives Ehcache error

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, ehcache, tomcat8, grails-2.5

I have Grails web project developed in 2.5.1 version. It works fine in Tomcat 7.0.63. When I deploy same running WAR file in Tomcat 8.0.33, it gives ehcache error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
```

I know it's due to ehcache old version, but the same war was working fine in Tomcat 7, so, what's wrong in Tomcat 8 ?

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

**Update:** If I replace all jar files of Tomcat 8 by Tomcat 7, then it works. But it seems like stupid thing to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was multiple ehcache jar files in project. Hibernate cache and spring cache, seems like spring cache was pointing to old jar in Tomcat8. We forced excluding **ehcache-core** and it worked.

For more info: [Exclude plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924347/grails-is-it-possible-to-exclude-a-plugin-dependency-of-another-plugin)