# Why is EhCache still being downloaded and initialized in my project

Tags: java, caching, grails, redis, ehcache

I have a grails 3 project where I am currently replacing an EhCache implementation, to use Redis cache server hosted by AWS and Redisson for the client connection. I have completely removed all references to EhCache as well as the dependency declaration in the gradle file, as well as even removing the .gradle folder referencing EhCache in net.sf.EhCache and the failsafe XML file that adds it into the project by default.

I cannot understand why i cannot git rid of this cache implementation, and prevent it from pulling this into/from the repo again and initializing it during the build and run process. Again there is no declaration for this ANYWHERE in the source code.
Below are a couple logs to describe what im seeing.

`2018-10-16 16:56:18,324   WARN     |  | localhost-startStop-1 |  |  | n.s.e.c.ConfigurationFactory | No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:.../net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.3/.../ehcache-2.10.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml`

```
2018-10-16 14:25:47,442 INFO     |  | localhost-startStop-1 |  |  | o.s.c.e.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean | Initializing EhCache CacheManager
```

Comment: A transitive dependency to be sure.  One of your other dependencies is pulling it in.

Comment: @BrentR am I just going to have to go digging through all my external dependencies/libraries looking for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [official docs](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html):

> The dependency-report command generates Ivy reports showing JAR
>   dependencies required by the application.

```
grails dependency-report runtime
```

Comment: I've discovered that it was in fact a transitive dependency from Springframework.spring-context-support as suggested by @BrentR. Right now I am looking into how one can exclude this dependency from the gradle build. If you perhaps had a link you could share if you know, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924347/grails-is-it-possible-to-exclude-a-plugin-dependency-of-another-plugin

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This got me to where i was trying to go